# from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext.webapp.util

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am a newbie to GAE. I am using eclipse +Pydev. I am getting this error

```
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
    ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext.webapp.util
```

Here is what I am importing

```
import cgi
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import MySQLdb
import os
import jinja2
```

I am using UBUNTU. I have searched this error in stackoverflow and I did not find any convincing answers.

I have even downloaded the appengine and reinstalled again and again but thats of no use.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

Please provide me with a correct answer like links etc. 
DO NOT reply with you can find about this on this link etc.. I have searched for many links on the net and I couldn't find the convincing explanation to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the App Engine SDK you downloaded is in your Python path. You can check what python thinks its path is by running python interactively:

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mock-1.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.5-osx_cocoa', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.5.0/lib/python2.7']
```

Alternatively you can add the SDK to the python path at runtime. For example, if you downloaded and unzipped to /home/username/google_appengine you could modify your python path in your script:

```
sys.path.append('/home/username/google_appengine')
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()

from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
```